# Angular ui-grid - DropDown Selection shows Id

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular http://ui-grid.info/. Facing issues when i have a dropdown in the Grid.

Following Code I have used for DropDown :-

```
objCombos = $scope.getComboValues('DEPARTMENT');

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
field: fieldName.toUpperCase(), displayName: displayName,
columnType: 'columnDb',
editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
editDropdownValueLabel: 'DEPARTMENT',
editDropdownOptionsArray: objCombos,
name: fieldName.toUpperCase()
});
```

Array for DropDown is like this `objCombos` :-

```
[
    { id: 1, department: 'Branch1' },
    { id: 2, department: 'Branch2' }
];
```

When i select & change dropdown value say from `Branch1` to `Branch2`, After changing the value it shows me the `id` of the selected value in dropdown list in this case `2`.

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Problem is Why after selection in DropDown the `id` is displayed instead of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it just by adding following property :-

```
editDropdownIdLabel: 'DEPARTMENT',
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting the `editDropdownIdLabel` to match the `editDropdownValueLabel` is okay for cases when the id is not really needed. That is, your underlying data structure stores strings ("Branch1", "Branch2") rather than integers (1,2).

If that is *not* the case, then use a custom filter. I recently had a situation where days of the week were stored in the back-end as integers (1-7), but the user expected to see the full name string in the grid.
Below is my solution - modified for this example:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter("branchFilter", function() {
    var vals = ["Branch1", "Branch2"];
    return function(id) {
        var i = id-1, ret = "?";
        if(i>=0 && i< vals.length) {
            ret = vals[i];
        }
        return ret;
    };
});
```

Then in the columnDefs, add `cellFilter: 'branchFilter'`.

**Having said that**, it is annoying that ui-grid assumes you need to distinguish between `id` and `value` in a dropdown, but then displays the id, except when editing. It is difficult to think of a case where that behaviour would be useful to a user.

I notice that you have the combo values stored in a separate array. Here is an approach that reuses this structure. First, put the combo values somewhere where they can be accessed across your app:

```
angular.module('myApp').value('ComboValues', {
    branches: [
        {id:1, value:"Branch1"},
        {id:2, value:"Branch2"},
        ...
    ]
});
```

And then tell a custom filter how to use the values:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter("comboFilter", function(ComboValues) {
    return function(id, comboName, idName, valName) {
        idName = idName || "id";      //optional - defaults to 'id'
        valName = valName || "value"; //optional - defaults to 'value'
        var opts = ComboValues[comboName];
        if(angular.isArray(opts)) {
            var ret = id; //default return value if no match found
            opts.some(function(opt) {  //look for matching option
                if(opt[idName]===id) {
                    ret = opt[valName];
                    return true; //break
                }//else keep looking
            });
            return ret;
        } else {
            return comboName+ " not an array";
        }
    };
});
```

Then in the columnDefs, use:
 `cellFilter: "comboFilter:'branch':'id':'value'"`
or if the default values are okay:
 `cellFilter: "comboFilter:'branch'"`

Notice that in this example the parameters need extra quotes, so the filter treats them as strings instead of scope variables. That is: `"comboFilter:'branch'"` not `"comboFilter:branch"`.